# The "add more logins" page needs a Stack Exchange account option

Tags: feature-request, bug, login, user-accounts, stack-exchange-openid

I asked a question about [How can I create a Stack Exchange account associated with an existing account?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308307/how-can-i-create-a-stack-exchange-account-associated-with-an-existing-account/308318?noredirect=1#comment260143_308318).

The problem was solved by Steven Penny's answer:

> you can manually enter your OpenID box, enter
>
> ```
> openid.stackexchange.com
> ```

This flow is weird. How does a user know he should enter such a string to create a native Stack Exchange account?

There should be a `stackexchange account option` on the [add more logins](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/login-add?returnUrl=%2Fusers%2Fcurrent) page.

**add more logins screenshot :**

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308307/how-can-i-create-a-stack-exchange-account-associated-with-an-existing-account